# git gui that shows branches well

Tags: git

I have been using gitk and am looking for something that shows all my branches and preferably the branches available on remotes. Could you recommend one?

EDIT: I do a lot of rebasing between branches and like to easily see which branch pulled from where. Its more useful to see all the branches

Comment: What exactly is the problem with gitk? It will show all your branches, and remote branches too if you like - try `gitk --branches`, `gitk --all`, or from inside, `view > new view` and check the appropriate box. Or are you just looking for a list of branches?

Comment: it's not that gitk is wrong or anything. I'm just looking for a client with a different emphasis.

Comment: @Arthur Ulfeldt: I was trying to ask you to clarify that emphasis - get an idea of what it is about how gitk shows branches that you don't like, to make it easier for others to tell if an alternative would be any better.

Comment: @jefromi if you put gitk --all in an answer i would vote for it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [gitg](http://trac.novowork.com/gitg/). I find the interface to be a lot nicer than gitk.

**EDIT:** The above link appears to be down (permanently?). From [Google's cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://trac.novowork.com/gitg/):

> gitg has been moved to GNOME
>   infrastructure. Bug reports can be
>   found on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=gitg). Sources on the
>   [GNOME ftp](ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gitg/0.0/). Development has been moved
>   to [GNOME git](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg).

Answer (score 31):

Why don't you try

```
gitk --all
```

If not, look at gitg or gitx

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at tools listed and described in "Graphical Interfaces" section of [Interfaces, frontends, and tools](http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) page on Git Wiki.

Beside **gitk** (history browser) and **git gui** (commit tool), both distributed with Git and both written in Tcl/Tk, there are among others the following graphical interfaces for Linux:

- [QGit](http://digilander.libero.it/mcostalba/), which uses Qt toolkit, in C++
- [Giggle](http://live.gnome.org/giggle), which uses GTK+ toolkit, in C
- [git-cola](http://cola.tuxfamily.org/), written in Python, uses PyQt4 toolkit
- [gitg](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/), a clone of GitX for GTK+/GNOME, in C
- [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) (**T**ext-mode **I**nterface for **G**it), uses ncurses, in C

There is also [git-instaweb](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-instaweb.html) to browse your working repository using gitweb.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much an application, but I find github's network view quite useful. `gitg` as peterjmag mentions is also great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) has worked well for me to see checkins with branches.